# Catching exceptions from list of tasks

Tags: async-await, task

I would like to know the proper way to handle exceptions in scenario like

---Updated code with solution---

```
var wt = new List<PendingSettlement>();
var ot = new List<PendingSettlement>();

var otTask = Task.Run(async () => ot = await LoadOtDataAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));
var wtTask = Task.Run(async () => wt = await LoadWtDataAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));
var tasks = new List<Task>
{
    otTask, wtTask
};

try
{
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
catch
{
    run.WarningMessage = GetInnermostExceptionMessage(wtTask.Exception) + Environment.NewLine + GetInnermostExceptionMessage(otTask.Exception);
    string GetInnermostExceptionMessage(Exception e)
    {
        if (e == null) return string.Empty;
        _logger.LogError(e, e.Message);
        while (e.InnerException != null) e = e.InnerException;
        return e.Message;
    }
}
```

Is there way to figure which inner exception corresponds to which task?

Comment: What's the point of using `Task.Run` when the methods are *already* asynchronous? The one place where `await` is needed here is in `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the tasks (e.g. `var t1 = Task.Run(...);`). Then, you can query the exception using `t1.Exception`. You can simply ignore the exception you get from `done.Wait();` then. I'd do that by writing `done.ContinueWith(_ => { }).Wait();` to avoid throwing and catching.

Comment: Thanks @usr ! I have followed your approach with some changes to suit my specific situation and updated the code block.

Comment: @Anand looks good. In my experience it is very bad for debugging to cut of exception infos like that. Just use `ToString` on the entire exception. You need to include the stack trace, type and inner exceptions to debug.

Comment: @Anand that log is still throwing away most of the info which is making debugging quite hard. There is no need to do any of this. Just log and print `e`.